# Why I get this syntax error in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I can't understand why I have this syntax error from mySQL:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cc.cursoID = c.cursoID JOIN cursosUsuarios cu ON c.cursoID = cu.cursoID JOIN u' at line 17

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
e.examenID, e.contenidoID, e.tituloExamen, 
u.userID, u.userEmail,
cu.userID, cu.cursoID, cu.examenes, cu.examenesRendidos,
co.contenidoID, co.tituloContenido,
cc.contenidoID, cc.cursoID,
c.cursoID, c.nombreCurso

FROM examenes ex 
JOIN contenidos co
ON ex.contenidoID = co.contenidoID

JOIN cursosContenidos cc
ON co.contenidoID = cc.contenidoID

JOIN cursos c
cc.cursoID = c.cursoID

JOIN cursosUsuarios cu
ON c.cursoID = cu.cursoID

JOIN usuarios u
ON cu.userID = u.userID

WHERE
cu.cursoID = 15
cu.userID = 1
```

This is line 17:

```
JOIN cursos c
cc.cursoID = c.cursoID
```

Comment: you forgot the `ON` before `cc.cursoID = c.cursoID`

Comment: Thanks! You're right! Please answer the question, so I can accept it :)

Comment: You're also missing an `AND` or `OR` keyword in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an "ON".

```
SELECT 
e.examenID, e.contenidoID, e.tituloExamen, 
u.userID, u.userEmail,
cu.userID, cu.cursoID, cu.examenes, cu.examenesRendidos,
co.contenidoID, co.tituloContenido,
cc.contenidoID, cc.cursoID,
c.cursoID, c.nombreCurso

FROM examenes ex 
JOIN contenidos co
ON ex.contenidoID = co.contenidoID

JOIN cursosContenidos cc
ON co.contenidoID = cc.contenidoID

JOIN cursos c
ON cc.cursoID = c.cursoID

JOIN cursosUsuarios cu
ON c.cursoID = cu.cursoID

JOIN usuarios u
ON cu.userID = u.userID

WHERE
cu.cursoID = 15 AND
cu.userID = 1
```

Comment: don't just repaste the whole thing. a single `on` is basically invisble in there. point out exactly WHERE the change was made. but otherwise, exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Line 17 should be

```
JOIN cursos c
ON cc.cursoID = c.cursoID
```

You forget to add "ON" with join.